# How to fetch SQL Row count from a time frame in PHP (yesterday, last 30 days)

Tags: php, mysql, time

I'm trying to fetch total results in a row from a selected time frame. I'll be making one for 30 days and placing it in its own container in the html site

and ill be making another one for Yesterday and placing it in its own container. Im using a code php file with the code, and im including this file in the html/php template using AJAX to refresh the code and make it real time.

here is the code (PS: i just edited the code i had for total results and tried to make it show for yesterday) [The date format in this particular field is 2019-03-05 10:10:59 if needed]

Name of the row im getting results from is "create_time" name of the table is t_house_operation_records

```
    <?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("xx:3306","xx","xx","xx");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="select count(*_
from t_house_operation_records
WHERE create_time IN (CURDATE(), CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY);
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0 ) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "$row[0]";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);


?>
```

Comment: And what's your question? What issue are you facing? What would you like help with? Please clarify, thanks

Comment: Are you sure that this is your query?

Comment: Other than the typos in your code `count(*_` should be `count(*)` and there is no trailing quote on the definition of `$sql` your code should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a count with SQL Query, but fetching row count from PHP result set object.

Either change query to not use count

```
$sql="select * from t_house_operation_records
WHERE create_time IN (CURDATE(), CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Or

Select first column of first row

```
$row = $result->fetch_array();
echo $row[0];
```